# How to convert to number in PHP Spread Sheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I have a PHP Spreadsheet code as follows

```
$cellAddress = 'Q' . $i_s1;
    $cell = $sheet->getCell($cellAddress);
    $style = $cell->getStyle();
    $style->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('_(* #.##0,00_);_(* (#.##0,00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)');
    
    if($resolve_1_s1 == "" && $closed_1_s1 == ""){
        $sheet->setCellValue('Q'.$i_s1, "0");
    } else {
        $totalDuration_s1 = calculateDuration($inistatus_s1, $created_1_s1, $resolve_1_s1, $closed_1_s1, $tahun_mulai, $tahun_selesai);
        $hasilAkhir_s1 = number_format($totalDuration_s1, 2, ',', '.');
        $sheet->setCellValue('Q'.$i_s1, $hasilAkhir_s1);
    }
```

but when I open the file, it appears as follows

[image]

I want the warning to disappear (make it as Convert to Number)

[image]

Comment: I think there is perhaps a misunderstanding between display format and the real value.
Values have always a dot as decimal separator, and the format with comma is only a display related issue. Instead you probably want that the values are directly recognized with the real value. So if your real values have a comma, you had to convert them to float numbers with a dot as separator -- even if they are displayed with a comma later.

Comment: Too make the difference more clear, assume you have float values with 8 digits after the decimal separator. You enter the values and can switch the display that only 2 of these digits are displayed. Nevertheless for calculations the 8 digits are used. This is the difference between value and display.